# How can I get my microphone to work on Windows 7 and Boot Camp 2.0?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows, microphone

I'm on windows 7 with bootcamp with a [bit older iMac](http://www.crunchgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/imac.jpg). I installed the bootcamp stuff from my Leopard DVD and I updated my bootcamp to 2.0. with Apple Software Update but the Microphone is still not working.

How should I make the microphone work?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have all the bootcamp drivers installed on the PC side of things?

Also, what type of microphone is it? Are there updated drivers for it?

Is Windows even recognizing a device is attached? Can you choose it and tell it to find the newest drivers?

EDIT:

Go to ControlPanel > SoundAndAudioDevices and click the 'Voice' tab. Make sure the 'Voice recording' device is correctly selected and click the 'Test hardware' button. You should be able to adjust the record volume. (One possible extra step: have to go to "advanced" and check-mark a box for "boost mic.")

> I then determined to try the microphone with headphones on. Sound comes through crystal clear to other people with them on. I don't understand why, but just know that it works fine now. So try some headphones for a temporary fix.

If none of this works for you, it seems that there is no fix for this issue yet and it will have to take another update to the Windows Bootcamp drivers for this issue to be resolved.

Comment: Well, it's the built in microphone in the iMac, as I sayed I installed the drivers from the Snow Leopard DVD, and I updated my bootcamp to the latest release, 2.0. Windows recognizes the device but doesn't works :\

Answer (score 1):

Having looked around a long time for answer to this question, I finally sorted mine out today. I have an iMac 27 inch (2013) running Windows 7 64-bit, through Boot Camp.  I have put up with using a headset microphone for a long as I can remember.

My solution today turned out to be stupidly simple. Go to Control Panel, Sound. Open the "Recording" tab. If you've got a headset connected, and you've got this problem, then I would assume the only thing you would see immediately is "Headset Microphone".

Now right click in the box and you should find an option which says "show disabled devices". When I selected that, my on-board microphone showed up as disabled, but at least I finally had an icon for it. Then it's a matter of right clicking on the disabled microphone (icon), select Properties and near the bottom of that screen there is an options box, which should include "Use this device (enable)". Selecting that option brought it all to life.